# Dropdown with remote filter clearing the value

Tags: extjs, dropdown

I have a `combobox` which loads using a ajax store to load the data. Everything works first time and I can select the item in the list coming from the server.

The problem is that when dropping the list down when there is a value in it, it hides the drop down list and clears the previously selected value.

[sencha fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3d1p)

Is this by design or is there a way to show the list filtering by the currently selected or typed value?

Answer (score 0):

After changing the `queryMode: 'local'`, the dropdown retains the value. I believe it is because with queryMode as remote, the data is fetched and set again on combobox and then after it sets the data, the combobox gets cleared.
But I have found a same example where the value is not getting cleared, you can try this [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/27jb&view/editor).